# Permission for Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

After that I press the '**Login to Facebook**' button and login, it will crash.
The problem is the permission for some stuff that I need to my app.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_social_login, container,
            false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("name", "user_birthday",
            "friends_birthday"));
```

When I comment this line, everything will work nice.

> authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("name", "user_birthday",
>                   "friends_birthday"));

But when I delete the comment I will get this error.

> 11-18 13:16:03.983: D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(2362): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success?error_code=100&error_message=Invalid+Scope%3A+name&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1384798557797%7D

Someone knows this error? Invalid Scope & name, something to do with the Graph API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open up your app to edit settings on the Facebook developers site, there is side bar with permissions.  Just type the ones you need in Extended Permissions.  I know this is more of a work around, but its the best option with the minimal code you have provided.

here is an example

```
// set permission list
          authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
          // session state call back event
          authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
           public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                      Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
                      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                              new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                                      if (user != null) { 
                                       Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
                                       Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                                       Log.i(TAG,"Name "+ user.asMap().get("name"));
                                       uName = user.asMap().get("name").toString();
                                       savePreferences();
                                       restorePreferences();

                                                                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                  }

           }
          });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Found it, and did put in "user_birthday" & "friends_birthday" :-)
But didn't found "name, fullname, firstname or lastname".

Comment: it should run with just name i believe

Comment: i have included an example

Comment: Thank you once again, will watch your example. And no, there is no "name" in the extended permission.. Weird.. time for Google it :)